# Sqlite3 .recover replaces accents with?

Tags: sqlite, unicode, encoding, data-recovery

I have a corrupted sqlite file. If I trí to open it, I get this error:

```
Error: database disk image is malformed
```

I tried to run `.recover`, like this:

```
sqlite3 corrupted.db ".recover" | sqlite3 recovered.db
```

I was able to open `recovered.db`, and almost everything is there, but the accented characters are replaced with `??`, for example:

- Original: `Pes jí bagetu`
- Restored: `Pes j?? bagetu`

It is unlikely, but possible, that the original file is not utf8 encoded.

If I run `.dump`, and produce an `sql` file with insert statement, then I don't experiene this issue. The accented charecters are displayed correctly in the `dump.sql`. But in this case, less than half of the database was exported, so I prefer `.recover`.

What do I wrong? The correct characters are there, as the dump shows, but for some reason, they are lost during the export.

Comment: Sounds like it's utf8 on one side and latin1 (or something) on the other.  Provide the HEX of the data.   `C3AD` is the utf8 hex for`í`